# Проблема проксирования с внешнего IP-Адреса на локальный ( NGINX )

Tags: php, nginx, ip, port

Всех приветствую, появилась проблема: я решил использовать Swoole для одного проекта. Для его работы сайт запускается с портом, приэтом на **http://127.0.0.1:9502**.

Работает сайт, как уже понятно, только с локальной машины, где я запускаю скрипт. Так вот, как мне сделать проброс через **Nginx** при обращении юзера к моему реальному **IP** на 127.0.0.1:port ?

Comment: Пытался использовать
location ~ "/port/(\d+)" {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$1/;
} - не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было добавить в **sites-available/default** следующее:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9502;
    }
```